# AEM TouchUI Components dialog

Tags: aem, sightly

I have multiple components that use another component as a child, not to generate all the content but it is a child component we recognized needed to be used multiple times so we created a child component that is being included:

The problem that I have run into is that in TouchUI the children component does not render its edit dialog when prompted. Has anyone run into this issue? Is there an extra property that must be set and that I may be missing or is this not allowed for touchUI?

I have tried to activate different components that may provide this feature but the ones that come close edit extra information in tabs rather than allowing them to act independently. This may be more of a ClassicUI use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have run into the same issue, in Touch UI sub nodes for child components are not created properly, we forced the creation of sub nodes and it worked, I know that there is a patch for that that daycare provided us, it was supposed to be fixed in SP2 but I guess not, here are the known issues from 6.1 https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes/known-issues.html
It seems that the problem may still persist, they talk about forcing the node in the template but the same work around work for sub nodes of a component.

See section Sites:

> Page Authoring: An error is thrown when trying to edit a component that is included in a component and it not yet present in the jcr:content of the page. Make sure the template adds the resources when the page is created (CQ-36949)

Comment: This seems to be a straight forward solution, one thing that we have is a parent component which can have 6 different types of child components, it will be interesting to make this integration by some how removing and adding data depending on what was selected on the parent. To make things more exciting some of the child compoents have a child component as well!

Comment: Make sure that each component create the node structure for its sub-components, but this is a big component you are building